# Minimum schema version

Tags: 8

I am updating my site from Drupal 8.2.1 to 8.2.4, while running update.php I encounter this problem

> The installed schema version does not meet the minimum.
>   Your system schema version is -1. Updating directly from a schema version prior to 8000 is not supported. You must [migrate your site to Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2179269) first.

I am unable to proceed any further. What exactly is causing this problem?[image: View image here]

Answer (score -1):

Use Drush. The following commands worked for me.

```
drush updb -y
drush cr
```

Comment: I am not sure Drush would solve the issue the OP has, which is the system schema version being -1. Do you have any evidence that Drush changes the system schema from -1 to a value higher than 7999?